# How to create Tabular Project for Analysis Services using REMOTE workspace server

Tags: ssas

I am trying to create a Visual Studio SSAS Tabular project connecting to a remote workspace server without success. I have no problem creating and deploying using localhost.

However I need the remote server to deploy to production or shared development server. I get error: "Cannot deploy model to the deployment database server 'xxxx.cloudapp.net'. Reason: You are not an Administrator on the deployment database server 'xxxx.cloudapp.net'."

I know I am reaching the server as otherwise the error is about not connecting to the server. I am already running Visual Studio as mydomain\adminuser and added it to the Analysis Server to make it administrator. However I am still getting that error. I can also connect remotely to the Analysis Server in Management Studio using that same user.

All the examples I've seen use localhost but have not found any using a shared/remote server even though some say it is possible without showing how. By the way, I understand using a local instance is better for development but I still need to deploy to a remote server. Hope that makes sense. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried using the SSAS deployment wizard? Worst case scenario you could copy the asdatabase file to the destination server (or a location accessible from there) and run the wizard there. http://www.bidn.com/blogs/DevinKnight/ssis/2298/ssas-%E2%80%93-deployment-wizard

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue when trying to deploy a SSAS Tabular model remotely. The [corresponding MSFT docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492138.aspx) further even discourages to deploy to production via Visual Studio.

But, a viable alternative is to deploy via XMLA:

1. Create your SSAS Tabular Model in Visual Studio and use your local SSAS instance for your workspace database
2. Launch SSMS connecting to your local SSAS instance
3. Right-click on your workspace database, and select `Script` > `Script Database As` > `CREATE to` > `File`
4. Open the generated XMLA file, and a) replace the temporary workspace database name with the database name on the deployment server, and b) search for the database connection string and re-add the password (see the note [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175406.aspx))
5. Launch SSMS connecting to your deployment SSAS instance
6. Open the XMLA file, and Execute it (by pressing `F5`)
7. Refresh the list of databases, right-click on the new one, and select `Process Database`

In case you already have a deployed database, then you need to select the `ALTER to` option instead of `CREATE to` in step 3 above.